# set a flag to 0 when installed and 1 when device reboots and 2 for rest of the intervals

Tags: android

In my application I am starting my service repetedly using `setRepeating()` at the interval of 3 min.

I want to set a flag such that it is set to flag=0 for 1st interval after installation, `flag=1` for interval after reboot and `flag=2` for rest of the intervals.

I am using shared preferences to store and access this flag. I can store flags successfully for boot in a bootUpReceiver. But unable to access it in my service. It always takes the value 2.

Code in BootUpReceiver:

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putInt("data_mode", 1);         
      editor.commit();
      Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      context.startActivity(i);  
   }
```

Code in Service:

```
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
 {
    final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    data_mode=settings.getInt("data_mode", 2);
    startLoggingService();
    startMonitoringTimer();
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
 }
```

Comment: Please post relevant code on how you use shared preferences to store and access the flag.

Comment: Have a look. I have edited